# save the frame data from matlab and later load and use it in visual studios project

Tags: matlab, visual-c++

I have a frame data of dimensions 320*240*3 in matlab. I want to save this data in local storage and later load it in Visual Studios project and save it in a pointer "_data" where definition of _data is const unsigned char* _data.

Saved frame data in a binary file(in MALTAB):

```
% Assuming 'frame' is your 240x320x3 video frame array
frame = ...;  % your data

% Open a file for writing
fileID = fopen('frame.bin', 'w');

% Write the frame data to the file
fwrite(fileID, frame, 'uint16');

% Close the file
fclose(fileID);
```

Loading it in C++ project:

```
    // The dimensions of the frame
    const size_t width = 320;
    const size_t height = 240;
    const size_t channels = 3;

    // Open the binary file
    std::ifstream file("frame.bin", std::ios::binary);

    // Check if we've opened the file successfully
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open the file." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Allocate memory for the frame data
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(width * height * channels);

    // Read the data directly into the buffer
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size());

    // Check if the read was successful
    if (!file) {
        std::cerr << "Error occurred while reading the file." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Close the file
    file.close();

    // Now buffer contains the frame data, and you can get a pointer to it
    const unsigned char* _data = buffer.data();

    // Use the _data pointer as needed
    // ...
```

But Im not getting the data correctly loaded. Kindly help